# How to implement a particular maths formula in Java?

Tags: java

```
package methods;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Billy
*/
public class Methods {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {      
    double Loanamount; // Loan amount from user
    double Aintrate; // User's annual interest rate
    double months; // Number of months on loan
    double monp; // Monthly payment
    double Mintrate; // Monthly interest rate
    double n; // The number of payments


    // declare an instance of Scanner to read the datastream from the keyboard.
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get user's loan amount
    System.out.print("Please enter your total loan amount: ");
    Loanamount = kb.nextDouble();

    // Get user's interest rate
    System.out.print("Please enter your annual interest rate as a decimal: ");
    Aintrate = kb.nextDouble();

    // Get user's number of months
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of months left on your loan: ");
    months = kb.nextDouble();

    // Calculate montly interest rate
    Mintrate = ((Aintrate / 12));

       System.out.println("Your monthly interest rate is " + " " + Mintrate);

    // Calculate number of payments
       n = ((months * 12));

    // Calculate monthly payment
```

My next job is to find out the *monthly payment* using this formula.

> M = P [ i(1 + i)^n ] / [ (1 + i)^n – 1]

Where

> M = monthly mortgage payment
>   P = The amount borrowed (Loanamount)
>   i = Monthly interest rate (Mintrate)
>   n = the number of payments

I tried the following but I just cant figure it out
`monp = Loanamount [Mintrate(1+ Mintrate)^n] / [(1+ Mintrate)^n-1 ];`

Comment: use `Math.pow`, that´s what you are looking for instead of `^`, Also your code example should include this formal, otherwise the rest of your code look quite irrelevan if it doesn´t produce any errors.

Comment: If using `double` type is still enough for estimation, it should be never used in financial calculations because of rounding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Math.pow` effectivley here.

Try using following in your code

```
monp = Loanamount*(Mintrate*Math.pow((1+ Mintrate),n)) / (Math.pow((1+ Mintrate),n-1 ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.pow` is what you need instead of `^`. Also you can't use `[` or `]`. You have to use parenthesis `(` and `)`.
More math functions can be found at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 1):

The method for `^` is called `Math.pow(double a, double b);` in Java.

Where `a` is the number to be raised `b` times.

Your formula would then look like `monp = Loanamount Math.pow((Mintrate(1+ Mintrate), n)) / (Math.pow((1+ Mintrate), n-1));`

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double))

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Math.pow(double,double)

OR  you could import the required class as..
`import static java.lang.Math.pow;`
and then use pow() function